# How to achive same slider as like showing in iPhone camera zoom slider

Tags: ios, uislider

I am facing a issue related to slider . i have requirement to implement a slider as like iPhone showing in camera zoom feature is it possible any how  ?

[image: I need to implement same as ios camera zoom slider]

I have try to follow many blog but result is not proper as i expected.

below is try code .

```
filterSlider?.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "zoomThumb"), for: .normal)
    filterSlider?.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "zoomThumb"), for: .highlighted)
```

[image: **And Result is :**]

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for `UISlider`, you'd have your answer already.

Create an image of your "transparent thumb", and call:

```
[_theSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621336-setthumbimage?language=objc

Comment: Ah - you want the line to be clipped inside the "hollow" thumb? You almost certainly need to write your own custom slider then. Shouldn't be to difficult - here is probably a really good starting point: https://github.com/ahmetws/DashedSlider